# Finding the weeks that hold the first of each Month in the current year

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to fill a `Set` with the weeks that hold the first of any month for the current year. For example, since the first week of the year normally holds the first day in January, I would simply add it to the SET as a 1, and then I would check for any other weeks in the year that holds the first of any month and add it to the SET as well. My current problem is finding out a way to check what weeks hold the first of any month in the current year. I thought at first of getting the first and last day of the a month but I've started to confuse myself at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

```
extension Date {

    func getStart(of component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Date? {
        return calendar.dateInterval(of: component, for: self)?.start
    }

    func getEnd(of component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Date? {
        return calendar.dateInterval(of: component, for: self)?.end
    }
}
```

Goal: 2023, Set = (1,5,9...etc)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overcomplicating this. Just loop through the 12 months of the year, create a date from year, month and day, and get its week-of-year.

```
let year = 2023
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
for month in 1...12 {
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: month/*, day: 1*/)
    guard let firstDayOfMonth = dateComponents.date else {
        print("unable to get first day of month")
        continue
    }
    let weekNumber = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: firstDayOfMonth)
    print(weekNumber) // or add it to a set or whatever
}
```

Comment: `day: 1` can be omitted

Comment: @Sweeper you can also just pass the calendar component as well and get the date property from DateComponents. `DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: month).date!`

Comment: @Sweeper Consider to unwrap firstDayOfMonth constant to prevent crash... es.: guard let firstDayOfMonth = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else { return }

Comment: @Fabio Thanks, edited. `continue` is probably better than `return`?

Comment: @Sweeper I think return is the right way because the app doesn't crash and nothing happens, with continue you could generate a non-value or a wrong value which could cause problems later... But I should elaborate I never had the problem ... Excellent starting point to study it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach with dedicated `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy:using:)` of `Calendar`.

Unfortunately the API has (still) a bug: It doesn't find any date if the year is specified in the matching components, so you have to check for the end *manually*.

Basically if you are dealing with weeks the `iso8601` calendar is preferable

```
let year = 2023
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
let queryComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, day: 1)
var weeks = Set<Int>()
let startOfYear = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 10))!
calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startOfYear,
                        matching: queryComponents,
                        matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                        using: { date, _, stop in
    if let date {
        let weekOfYearComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .year], from: date)
        if weekOfYearComponents.year! > year { stop = true }
        weeks.insert(weekOfYearComponents.weekOfYear!)
    }
})
print(weeks)
```